# Set custom symbol to HighCharts legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, legend

I want to set custom symbol to legend item. Currently I have rectangle. I need rectangle with tick (like colorful checked checkbox). 
According to documentation, I can just customize elements like text near that symbols.

But in case I've made all elements on plot like custom image ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/)) then legend symbol will be changed.

Can I customize legend symbol without customizing points on plot?

```
series:[
     {
            name: 'Image symbol',
            data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5],
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
            }
        }
]
```

Comment: This might help: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/studies/legend-custom-symbol/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use legend.labelFormatter for adding legend symbols. For example you can use useHTML: true for your legend and then add an image to your legend item as a symbol:

```
legend: {
  useHTML: true,
  symbolWidth: 0,
  labelFormatter: function() {
    var name = this.name;
    var img = '<img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Check_Box_Noun_project_10759.svg/2000px-Check_Box_Noun_project_10759.svg.png" width = "10px" height = "10px">';
    return img + '  ' + name;
  }
},
```

Here you can find an example how it can work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ryd061r0/

You can also wrap drawLegendSymbol method as Barbara Laird suggested.